# vyper no mappings allowed when adding a function to initialize a struct that has a map inside

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, mapping, struct, vyper

#### Version Information

- vyper Version (output of `vyper --version`): 0.1.0b17+commit.eaa6754
- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- Python Version - 3.6.2
- Environment (output of `pip freeze`):

asttokens==2.0.3
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pycryptodome==3.9.7
six==1.14.0
vyper==0.1.0b17

#### What's your issue about?

Can't populate a single struct without adding an inside mapping when using a struct declaration variable inside a function

```
struct Teddy:
    id: uint256
    year: uint256
    component: map(uint256, uint256)

teddies: map(uint256, Teddy)

@public
def __init__():
    self.teddies[0].id = 0
    self.teddies[0].year = 2019

@public
def create_teddy(teddy_name: string[20]):
  teddy: Teddy = Teddy({
        id: 3,
        year: 1922
      })
```

output:

```
vyper.exceptions.InvalidType: line 4:15 No mappings allowed for in-memory types, only fixed-size arrays
     3     year: uint256
---> 4     component: map(uint256, uint256)
----------------------^
```

#### How can it be fixed?

tip: strange, cleaning the function 'create_teddy' you just compile it... the context is affecting how the compiler 'understand' the struct declaration. I also tried to:

```
 self.teddies[0] = Teddy({
        id: 3,
        year: 1922
      })
```

but got a

```
vyper.exceptions.TypeMismatch: line 15:2 Keys don't match for structs, missing component
```